# Recursively calculate path for each item of the self referencial hierarchial table

Tags: sql-server, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a table like this (SQL Server 2008):

```
[ATTACHMENTS].[ID]
[ATTACHMENTS].[Name]
[ATTACHMENTS].[DocumentID],
[ATTACHMENTS].[ParentAttachmentID]
```

If `[ParentAttachmentID]` is `NULL` or `0` - then the record is top. Otherwise - the record is a child. Every child can be (and can't be) the parent of some other child elementS.

I need to calculate "path" for every record of the table. Path is:

`ParentAttachment.Path + ' > ' + Attachment.Path` (ParentAttachment.Path is recursive)

I try something like this:

```sql
WITH attachments AS (
 SELECT *,
     [ATTACHMENTS].[Name] AS Path
     FROM [ATTACHMENTS]
     WHERE  [ATTACHMENTS].[ParentAttachmentID] IS NULL
            OR [ATTACHMENTS].[ParentAttachmentID] = 0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT a.*,
     c.Path + ' > ' + a.[Name]
     FROM [ATTACHMENTS] a
         INNER JOIN attachments c
             ON a.[ParentAttachmentID] = c.[ID]
)
```

But it doesn't work properly (Path is invalid for some elements due to duplicates as I think). Where I made a mistake? Please, help me to fix this problem.

**UPD 2**: CSV with data from table [ATTACHMENTS] - http://pastebin.com/WMd6HJ7j
CSV with result of recursive query:  http://pastebin.com/7pqs0dx1

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you get?

I think that you are not specifying your datatypes explicitly enough. The size of Path is the size of the anchor start point: ATTACHMENTS.Name. Which probably would be a varchar(100) or so.

Then when you keep recursively growing your path, it might run out of space. The CTE itself looks fine. I had a go at it using explicit sizes, then it work fine.

```
CREATE TABLE #Attachments
    (
      Id INT PRIMARY KEY
             NOT NULL ,
      ParentId INT NULL ,
      Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );

-- some sample data:
-------------------------------------

-- 100 top level attachments (lvl0)
INSERT  INTO #Attachments
        ( Id ,
          ParentId ,
          Name
        )
        SELECT  A.Rnum ,
                NULL ,
                'A' + CAST(rnum AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM    ( SELECT TOP 100
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT
                                                              1
                                                         ) ) AS Rnum
                  FROM      sys.messages
                ) A;

-- attachments linked to lvl0
INSERT  INTO #Attachments
        ( Id ,
          ParentId ,
          Name         
        )
        SELECT  1000 + A.Rnum ,
                A.Rnum ,
                'A' + CAST(( rnum + 1000 ) AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM    ( SELECT TOP 1000
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT
                                                              1
                                                         ) ) AS Rnum
                  FROM      sys.messages
                ) A;

-- attachments linked to lvl1
INSERT  INTO #Attachments
        ( Id ,
          ParentId ,
          Name         
        )
        SELECT  10000 + A.Rnum ,
                1000 + A.Rnum ,
                'A' + CAST(( rnum + 10000 ) AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM    ( SELECT TOP 1000
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT
                                                              1
                                                         ) ) AS Rnum
                  FROM      sys.messages
                ) A;

-- Query:
-------------------------------------

WITH    Att ( Id, Name, ParentId, Lvl, NamePath, IdPath )
          AS ( SELECT   P.Id ,
                        P.Name ,
                        P.ParentId ,
                        CAST(0 AS INT) AS Lvl ,
                        CAST(P.[Name] AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS NamePath ,
                        CAST(P.[Id] AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS IdPath
               FROM     #ATTACHMENTS P
               WHERE    P.[ParentId] IS NULL
                        OR P.[ParentId] = 0
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   A.Id ,
                        A.Name ,
                        A.ParentId ,
                        P.Lvl + 1 ,
                        CAST(P.NamePath + ' > ' + A.Name AS VARCHAR(1000)) ,
                        CAST(P.IdPath + '\' + CAST(A.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) AS VARCHAR(1000))
               FROM     #ATTACHMENTS A
                        INNER JOIN Att P ON A.ParentId = P.Id
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Att;

DROP TABLE #Attachments;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement seems correct to me:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      Code NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      ParentCode NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '1', NULL ),
        ( '2', NULL ),
        ( '1.1', '1' ),
        ( '1.1.1', '1.1' ),
        ( '1.1.2', '1.1' ),
        ( '1.2', '1' ),
        ( '1.2.1', '1.2' ),
        ( '2.1', '2' ),
        ( '2.2', '2' );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   Code ,
                        ParentCode ,
                        ISNULL(Code, '') AS Path
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    ParentCode IS NULL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.Code ,
                        t.ParentCode ,
                        Path + ISNULL(' > ' + t.Code, '') AS Path
               FROM     @t t
                        JOIN cte c ON c.Code = t.ParentCode
             )
    SELECT  * FROM    cte
```

Output:

```
Code    ParentCode  Path
1       NULL        1
2       NULL        2
2.1     2           2 > 2.1
2.2     2           2 > 2.2
1.1     1           1 > 1.1
1.2     1           1 > 1.2
1.2.1   1.2         1 > 1.2 > 1.2.1
1.1.1   1.1         1 > 1.1 > 1.1.1
1.1.2   1.1         1 > 1.1 > 1.1.2
```

Comment: But it return records with NULL path :| , so why I sak for it . I attach link to the data from the table ATTACHMENTS to my question

Comment: You have NULLs in your data in Name column. So this `cast((c.[Path] + N' > ' + a.[Name]) ` evaluates to NULL. Thats Why you get NULLs in result. See how I use `ISNULL` function: `Path + ISNULL(' > ' + t.Code, '') AS Path`

Comment: Hmm, yes. it's fix path result (no NILs now). But anyway it's wrong :( And I get 65 records instead of 69 (from [ATTACHMENTS])

Comment: Take a look on ID 45. You have ParentID 45 pointing on itself

Comment: Yes, I fix it now. But there is wrong pathes anyway.

Comment: I update my ATTACHMENTS table data. And added an result of recursive query, watch my question ( link to results http://pastebin.com/7pqs0dx1 ) As you see, records with years has a wrong path. Thanx!

Comment: Tell me any one ID that has incorrect path, and what path it should contain instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to set different names for table and the name after `WITH`, and use the second name for second part of the join. Consider `attachments1` in below code:

```
WITH attachments1 AS (
  -- anchor
 SELECT *,
     [ATTACHMENTS].[Name] AS [Path]
     FROM ATTACHMENTS
     WHERE  [ATTACHMENTS].[ParentAttachmentID] IS NULL
            OR [ATTACHMENTS].ParentAttachmentID = 0
 UNION ALL
 --recursive member
 SELECT a.*,
        cast((c.[Path] + N' > ' + a.[Name]) as nvarchar(500)) as [Path]
     FROM ATTACHMENTS a
         INNER JOIN attachments1 c
             ON a.ParentAttachmentID = c.[ID]
)

SELECT * FROM attachments1
```

You can get the `Path` from the recursive member.